# In Inform 6, what is LibSerial and how does it factor into action-based dispatching?

Tags: interactive-fiction, inform

By no small amount of pain, I have discovered that the following  Inform 6 source doesn't work as expected: instead of calling the right branch of `Bar.after` based on the current action, it always prints `Called from Foo`:

```
Global action;

[ R_Process a;
    action = a;
    indirect(#actions_table-->a);
];

Verb 'foo' * -> Foo;
Verb 'baz' * -> Baz;

Object Bar "bar"
  with after [;
    Foo: "Called from Foo";
    Baz: "Called from Baz";
    ];

[ BazSub;
    print "[Baz]^";
    Bar.after();
];

[ FooSub;
    print "[Foo]^";
    Bar.after();
];

[ Main;
  <foo>;
  <baz>;
];
```

Running it produces the following output:

```
[Foo]
Called from Foo
[Baz]
Called from Foo
```

However, if I prepend the following three lines to the Inform script above, then it works as expected:

```
Constant LibSerial "foo";
Global reason_code;
Property additive life;
```

Now the output becomes:

```
[Foo]
Called from Foo
[Baz]
Called from Baz
```

The three lines are all important:

- Omitting the definition of the `LibSerial` constant (i.e. keeping the other two lines only) causes `Called from Foo` to be printed from both callbacks.
- Omitting the declaration of the (as far as I can see, unused) variable `reason_code` gives the following compile-time error:

  ```
  "<constructing output>", line -65535: 
  Error:  No such constant as "reason_code"
  ```
- Omitting the declaration of the `life` property causes a similar compile-time error:

  ```
  "<constructing output>", line -65535: 
  Error:  No such constant as "life"
  ```

So basically my question is, **what is going on here?** What is the effect of defining `LibSerial` and why does it need the `life` property and the `reason_code` global variable to be declared?